# Can I freeze/save http requests and reply to them later from another server?

Tags: node.js, http, web-services, https, network-programming

I want to freeze/save http requests, give them to another server, and then after 10 minutes reply to them through another nodejs app. Is that possible?

(yes correct, the user would wait 10 minutes for his response, but that is not a problem)

for more details why I want to do that, read here: [Can I implement Discourse Message Bus with Apache Kafka/GCP-PubSub with freezing http requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70142858/can-i-implement-discourse-message-bus-with-apache-kafka-gcp-pubsub-with-freezing)

Comment: I think you can earn similar implementation by using : https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the timeout from the client side. If timeout is over , you cannot send a http response back to the client as the client is not listening for one. Also most clients are behind NAT, so that timeout is the only window you have to answer

Comment: thanks for the response! i wasn't specific enough, sorry my fault. - the timeout doesn't matter, to keep it simple: e.g my database(-server) aggregates every 10 minutes a heavy ML query which will be ready after another 10 minutes. - so if the http request of the client runs out because of NAT timeout, I will just fire another new HTTP request. so this is no problem (y) every 10minutes the DB server will respond to all requests, and won't care if a response won't get delivered because of timeout

Comment: If you controll the client than why not go for another type of connection like websocket or bare tcp?  This long requests and responses with statefull connections are not meant for http